# ¿Cómo llamo al controlador desde AJAX?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

MI AJAX CODIGO

```
     $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "comprarbloqueo")',               
                data: "",
                contentType: 'json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Success');
                    $(data).each(function (i, row) {
                        //  alert("Entroo");                        
                        vTxtFechaInicioCom = row.COMBLO_FechaInicioCompra;
                        vTxtFechaFinCom = row.COMBLO_FechaFinCompra;
                    });
                    alert(vTxtFechaInicioCom)
                    $("#txtNombre").val(vTxtFechaInicioCom);
                    $("#txtPrecioVu").val(vTxtFechaFinCom);
                },
});
```

///////////CONTROLADOR ////////////

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CompraBloViewModel comprarbloqueo = new CompraBloViewModel();
        comprarbloqueo.BuscaPorNombre();
        return View("_Listadocomprarbloqueos", comprarbloqueo.ComprarBloqueos);
    }
```

Comment: El codigo lo tienes dentro de la vista o en un archivo js aparte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'@Url.Action("Index", "comprarbloqueo")'` es sintaxis de razor que javascript no puede interpretar directamente. 
Una opción es escribir la ruta en el url. Cómo no manejas parámetros no debes de tener problemas para llamar a Index().

```
$.ajax(
       {
           url: '/comprarbloqueo/Index',               
           data: "",
           contentType: 'json; charset=utf-8',
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (data) {
               alert('Success');
               $(data).each(function (i, row) {
                   //  alert("Entroo");                        
                   vTxtFechaInicioCom = row.COMBLO_FechaInicioCompra;
                   vTxtFechaFinCom = row.COMBLO_FechaFinCompra;
               });
               alert(vTxtFechaInicioCom)
               $("#txtNombre").val(vTxtFechaInicioCom);
               $("#txtPrecioVu").val(vTxtFechaFinCom);
           },
       });


public ActionResult Index()
{
    CompraBloViewModel comprarbloqueo = new CompraBloViewModel();
    comprarbloqueo.BuscaPorNombre();
    return View("_Listadocomprarbloqueos", comprarbloqueo.ComprarBloqueos);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuando el código ajax está en un archivo JavaScript o dentro del cuerpo de la vista?

Comment: Esta sintaxis de ajax  es de la librería de jquery. Para tener una mejor administración de tu código, ten todo en archivos separados.